# Shortening the time of Stack usage in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, stack

I am working on a coding problem.

https://www.acmicpc.net/problem/1406

I have written up a solution for this,

```
front = []
back = []

word = input()
count = int(input())

for a in word:
    front.append(a)

for i in range(count):
    command = input().split()
    if command[0] == "P":
        front.append(command[1])
    elif command[0] == "L":
        if front:
            back.append(front.pop())
    elif command[0] == "D":
        if back:
            front.append(back.pop())
    else:
        if front:
            front.pop()

while (back):
    front.append(back.pop())

print(''.join(map(str, front)))
```

However, I keep getting TimeOut error when I submit.
How can I change something to run this code faster in Python? Or is this an inherent problem of the language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's imagine you have a million characters and two million commands.

1. You need to iterate a million characters first and create a really big array.
2. For each L and D operation, you need to pop and push. In this example, you do this almost two million times.
3. In the edge case, when we were only making L operations, you will have to iterate the whole `back` and append it to `front`

I bet all 3 cases are tested.

You may always try to speed up performance with deque https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque

But I would recommend to not use lists at all. You can get away with just operating on `word` and remembering index, at which the cursor is right now.